# Existence of increasing function $f:\mathbb N\longrightarrow X$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that given an arbitrary subset $X\subset \mathbb N$ there exists an increasing function $f:\mathbb N\longrightarrow X$?

This may seem elementary, but I'm stuck on it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is false if $X$ is finite, unless perhaps you mean "weakly increasing," which of course, would be trivial (choose a constant function)

Comment: It depends on whether you mean "increasing" or "nondecreasing". If you mean increasing, then this is plainly false.

Comment: Increasing means $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not true if $X$ is finite.  If $X$ is infinite, it has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$, and since it is non-empty, it has a least element $x_0$,
then $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ has a least element $x_1$.  In this way, we can recursively define a sequence $x_n=\min(X\setminus\{x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1}\})$.  Now,
the map $f:\Bbb N\to X$ defined by $f(n)=x_n$ will be increasing.

Comment: You're welocme. :)

Comment: Is the cardinality consideration necessary for defining the map? I'd think just $X\subset\Bbb N$ (and infinite) is enough.

Comment: Suppose $X$ is finite.  It has a largest element say, $x$.  If there is such a function, $f$, then $f(n)=x$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, but then $f(n+1)\le f(n)$, and so is not increasing.